# Can't create ts with zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I ran into an error, when I tried to create a time series with zoo package. I have a csv file, with values like this.

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
7-Oct-16,173.65,175.30,170.45,173.60,44266097
6-Oct-16,173.00,175.35,173.00,174.25,41362124
...
```

```r
barc<-read.zoo("barc2.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE, format = "%Y-%b-%d")
```

I try to use this code, however I receive an error, that index has bad entries at every row. I do not understand what is the source of the error. The dates are in the first place, which should be used as the index.

Comment: I mean format="%d-%b-%y"

Answer (score 0):

Using the file created reproducibly in the Note at the end the code shown in the question does work if we fix the `format=` argument:

```
library(zoo)

read.zoo("barc2-test.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE, format = "%d-%b-%y")
##              Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
## 2016-10-06 173.00 175.35 173.00 174.25 41362124
## 2016-10-07 173.65 175.30 170.45 173.60 44266097
```

Note that the code can be shortened to:

```
read.csv.zoo("barc2-test.csv", format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

### Note

We can create the file in a reproducible manner as shown below.  We have changed the filename so it won't overwrite barc2.csv.

```
Lines <- "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
7-Oct-16,173.65,175.30,170.45,173.60,44266097
6-Oct-16,173.00,175.35,173.00,174.25,41362124
"
cat(Lines, file = "barc2-test.csv")
```